# How to generate a unique integer for the identifier string in distributed environment?

Tags: distribution

There are about 100,000,000 identifier strings coming from other system, and we should set a unique integer (INT32) for each string, the logic like:

if find(str) return str's integer id
else generate max(int) + 1 for str and return

how to implement it in distributed system?

Comment: How max(int) + 1 supposed to work? Are you going to return INT64?

Comment: in distributed environment, how to keep the operation of "get max then +1" is an atomic operation?  Just let each string has an integer ID.

Comment: What I'm saying Max(INT32)+1 is beyond INT32 representation

Comment: Do you know upfront how many distributed nodes you have?